# Can a register remove the race condition in this case?

Tags: digital-logic, race-condition

My book has this example of a race condtion:[image]

The race condition is: If D and CLK is 1, and CLK goes to zero, then we want the output Q to remain 1, however if the inverter is slow compared to the other logic gates then the output may be zero.

**Question:**
Later in the book the author says that we can avoid race conditions by inserting registers in the loops. Can we do it in this case with our loop here? Is it enough with one flip-flop?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the single inverter with two inverters. The first inverter has \$CLK\$ as its input and drives the bottom AND gate with \$\overline{CLK}\$. The second inverter takes its input from \$\overline{CLK}\$ (the bottom AND gate input) and drives the top AND gate with \$\overline{\overline{CLK}} = CLK_{DELAYED}\$.

Comment: My first thought was to simply add a buffer on the top AND gate’s input pin to match the delays, but that provides no guarantee. Your solution leaves no doubt.

Comment: @BlairFonville, an additional delaying gate wouldn't be the solution. The gate delays aren't reliably equal across temperature and voltage but, in any event, that ignores the routing delays. Trying to solve a stability race condition using gate delays introduces all these problems that can be easily designed out in synchronous logic.

Answer (score -1):

That is a register (albeit a flawed one)

It can be cured by replacing it with a register, more complex equivalent schemes will also work.